# Having a hard time understanding & implementing some Ruby code

Tags: ruby, inject

```
myitem.inject({}) {|a,b| a[b.one] = b.two; a}
```

Where:

myitem is a class which holds an array or pair objects (pair objects have two fields in them one and two)

I am not sure what the above code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with an empty map, set its value for the b.one key to b.two.

In other words, for every item in the "myitem" collection, create a map entry. The key will be an item's "one" value. That map entry's value will be the item's "two" value.

The block given to "inject" receives two parameters. The first is the "accumulator". It's initial value in this case is the empty map passed to "inject". The second parameter is the current item in the collection. In this case, each item in the collection.

The block must return whatever will be used as the *next* accumulator value, in this case, the map. We want to keep using the same map, so when we're done, the "inject" method will return the map with all the key/value pairs.

Without saving the results of the inject it's a bit worthless.

Comment: So what would the actual inject look like? The actual method I mean

Comment: [Use the source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

Comment: @JeremyGuy It would also need to return "o" at the end of the method. It's more or less correct as phrogz wrote it, though, for this use case.

Comment: `inject` (simplified for the above usage) would look something like this in pure Ruby: `def inject(o); each{ |v| o = yield(o,v) }; o; end`

Comment: @JeremyGuy It's a method on Enumerable (or array, or whatever), not standalone. If you want to write it as a standalone method, you need to pass in the enumerable as well: `def inject(e, o); e.each { ... etc ...`

Answer (score 1):

It's a pedantic way of writing

```
h = {}
myitem.each { |b| h[b.one] = b.two }
```

or to be closer to your original code

```
a = {}
mytem.each { |b| a[b.one] = b.two }
```

(I personnaly hate this pattern (and people who use it) as it needs the `; a` at the end, losing all the functional aspect of inject. (Using a side-effect function inside a 'functional pattern', and then realizing that the later function  (a[..]) doesn't return the expecting object is just wrong, IMO).

Inject is normal use to 'fold' a list into a result like

```
[1,2,3].inject(0) { |sum, x| sum+x } 
=> 6 # (0+1+2+3)
```

here `sum` is the result of the last call to the block, `x` is each value on the list and `0` is the initial value of `sum`.

```
[2,3].inject(10) { |p,x| p*x }
=> 60 # 10*2*3
```

etc ...

Comment: What does an inject do? I don't really understand

Comment: The reason it's used is for chaining; each doesn't return the hash.

Comment: In other words, I don't think "pedantic" really makes sense here.

Comment: If oyu use 1.9's `each_with_object` you don't need to add the `; a`.

Comment: @dave I think it does. It's pedantic because it's a complicated version of simple code. By complicated I mean, not straight forward to understand (as it deserves a question here) and doesn't have any benefit. The benefit of chaining (and avoiding '; h' in the simplest version) is lost by the fact you have do add '; a' in the inject. I've seen this pattern lot, and seen lots of people forgetting the '; a'

Comment: If it did the exact same thing as `each`, I *might* agree. But it doesn't. If you want to chain it to something else that operates on the map, it's a cleaner option (delta `each_with_object` post 1.9.1).

Comment: The functional version (and so cleaner) is inject { |a,b| a.merge(b.one => b.two } but itn's not efficient memorywise. The cleanest IMHO is to use facet and myitem.mash { |b| [b.one, b.two] }

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[my_item.map {|object| [object.one, object.two]}]
```

is another way to do it.